# Kubernetes Helm: not a valid chart repository

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

According to [cert-manager installation docs](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/) jetstack repository should be added:

> $ helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io

It gives error message:

> Error: looks like "https://charts.jetstack.io" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: unknown field "serverInfo"

What are the ways to fix the issue?

Comment: I have tried with both helm 2 and helm 3 and both got results ""jetstack" has been added to your repositories".

Comment: I can confirm this issue using helm 3.3.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks to be caused by a patch done in Version 3.3.2 of Helm for security based issues.

Reference Issue: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/8761

Security Patch: https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/8762

Comment: Thanks! Indeed fixed it by downgrading. Removed helm, followed https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/ but run `./get_helm.sh --version v3.3.1`

Comment: This is a major surprise, other repos are affected too (like devspace.io which hosts loft)

Answer (score 1):

**Update 24 Sept 2020**

This is now also fixed in Helm 3.3.3. To upgrade to the latest Helm version in Windows `choco upgrade kubernetes-helm`